# bundle update not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

This is the error I'm getting with bundle update:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0)

```
rails (~> 5.2) was resolved to 5.2.0, which depends on
  railties (= 5.2.0)

sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
  railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

web-console (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
  railties (>= 4.0)
```

I tried to check my rails -v and it told me to run bundle update and when I did, I got this error. Can anyone help ? I'm quite lost

Comment: Delete Gemfile.lock and run bundle again

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because Bundler attempts to satisfy the version requirements of the dependencies, but is unable to do so as `rails 5.2.0` requires the gem `railties` in the version `5.2.0`, while `coffee-rails 4.1.0` needs a version of `railties` which is less than `5.0` but greater than or equal `4.0.0`.  Those two requirements are conflicting with each other.

Luckily, solving that problem is really easy: all you need to do is to bump the version requirement of the `coffee-rails` gem to `~> 4.2`.  This can be done by changing the line `gem "coffee-rails", "~> 4.1.0"` (or similar) in your `Gemfile` to the following:

```
gem "coffee-rails", "~> 4.2"
```

After that change, `bundle update` should work just fine.